CMake could not find toolchain file
Enviroment:Windows 11
hi, im encountering an issue building sonic cd regarding CMake and/or vcpkg. i know other answers exist on the web, but those answers were either irrelevent or didn't help.
H:\games\Sonic-CD-11-Decompilation>cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=H:/Programs/nerdy github stuff/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=H:/Programs/nerdy github stuff/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   "stuff/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/"


CMake Error at H:/Programs/nerdy github stuff/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:152 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file: H:/Programs/nerdy
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


Parameters with spaces should be wrapped in double quotes. In the current form you have -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=H:/Programs/nerdy, github and stuff/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake as separate parameters.

like this? cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="H:/Programs/nerdy github stuff/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="H:/Programs/nerdy github stuff/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/"
